# Somebody help i have been experiencing intrusive thoughts and i need answers

Tags: allah, dua

So i have been having bad thoughts about allah since a month now it became worse i started tp think about bad duas for example like (god dont forgive me forever) but i dont want that dua to happen even though its stuck into my mind and i cant stop thinking about it every day i always do bad duas because of my intrusive thoughts i dont want that dua to be granted im scared and i cant control my thoughts i tried to read quran but nothing is working,i always get interrupted by these bad dua thoughts.Will allah accept these bad duas or no because i have intrusive thoughts?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 2):

Oh sister/brother i have the same problem. Try maybe with listening to Ruqya and removing music out of your life. The best is to arrange someone who will do Ruqyah on you InshaAllah. Those are clearly thoughts of Shaytaan which cannot be removed with medication.

So try:

- Ruqyah
- Listening to Quran a lot and let Surah Al-Baqarah recite in the background (so that you can clearly hear the recitor)
- Always be on Wu‘du
- See what sins you may be doing which could be the trigger of those thoughts, and try to repent for them
- Do more good deeds

I hope this helps and please consider contacting a skeikh or an imam who could help you there a lot more inshaAllah ❤️❤️

السلام عليكم

Answer (score 1):

Some dude (idk who it was but it was either European or American) once said "Being able to entertain ideas without believing them is the sign of a strong mind." Don't worry about those thoughts. The simple fact that you are worried and care enough to ask a question like this shows that you are strong in your faith.

Answer (score 0):

i also have been having similar that thoughts. my biggest fear is leaving islam. but I always say in my heart "god I'm leaving islam" I can not control it. it's always pops up almost every Salah. even though I don't mean to say that but it's just pops out automatically (I can't control it. I think that is a syaitan. so what I do is just say "o Allah please forgive me, you know that it's not me. it's syaitan" so then I don't try to forget it. because the more I try to forget it the more it will pop up. but I don't know wether it's the right solution or not. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know **it's not normal** what i'm going to say now, but please understand me and help me too : i start thinking of **bad things** about **Allah** and **life**, even when i'm **praying**. I think it's about my **negative doubting** like: "If we are just souls in the day of judgment, what's going to happen?", "What's going to happen when the world will be entirely empty of humans?", and so many like that... i make duas like : "Allahouma a'oudou bika min wasswassati shaya'attin", and i hope one day my mind can be more clean of these bad thoughts. I really love Allah, because **he's my everything in this life** and i'm sure that when i want to cry, and suddenly comes something that makes me happy, **he's the one who wanted me to be happy**... i'm **afraid** that one day... Allah **gives up** on realizing my douas **because of these thoughts**... i'm afraid that these thoughts changes my life **into a bad life**...

I hope that all persons that have bad thoughts about life, Allah, and other things, can think of beautiful things instead of negative things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with doubts is sound information and knowledge. You may wish to write down those doubts in order to have a clearer idea regarding their content. Also, it is good to know that there are many really good articles online with addresses your question. If you google "dealing with doubts about Islam" many excellent articles will show up in your search. Also, I advise you to not spend too much time alone, but be in the company of good and righteous people. I know that is a bit challenging right now but try as much as you can. Also, I highly recommend the online series "Why Islam is True" with Shaykh Hamza Karamali which you can view at the following link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4mTEQpP9b5FGEZMhSfJVK0N6miIN2DhP

May Allah makes things easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum

I sometimes have these thoughts too. In the past they have been so strong that I felt as if I had to go to sleep just to get away from them. I noticed they also often came to me at a time of stress or anxiety.

The fact that you are worried about such thoughts and are continuing doing duas and reading The Qur'an is a sign that you have imaan. If the thoughts were from the person themselves then obviously it wouldn't cause them distress because it would be from their own desires so the fact that you dislike these thoughts and are afraid of having them is actually a positive sign on your side. These thoughts are actually the whispers of the Shaitaan and Allah knows which are your duas and which are the whispers from the Shaitaan (waswasa). So there's no way that He will answer them as if it's your own dua. So don't worry about that.

This is mentioned in the following hadith:
Actions are judged by intentions (Bukhari/Muslim)

So you wouldn't be accountable for these thoughts especially as you dislike them

One of the Sahabah complained to the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) about waswas during prayer, and he said: “The Shaytan comes between me and my prayers and my recitation, confusing me therein.” The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “That is a devil called Khanzab. If he affects you, seek refuge in Allah from him and spit drily to your left three times.” He (the Sahabi) said, I did that and Allah took him away from me. (Narrated by Muslim, 2203)

So when you seek refuge in Allah from the accursed shaitaan by saying "au'thoo billahi min ashaitaan-i-rajeem" (I seek refuge with Allah from the accursed Shaitaan) while blowing to the left after each time of saying it (3x) then it should in shaa Allah make the Shaitaan leave you alone.

Allah teaches in The Qur'an that when an evil suggestion comes to you from the Shaitaan then seek refuge in Allah. Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Knowing (See Qur'an 41:36).

It should also help by reciting the last 3 surahs of the Holy Qur'an (Ikhlas, Falaq and Naas) 3x in the morning and 3x in the evening every single day and by reciting ayatul kursi (Qur'an 2:255) 3x in the morning and 3x in the evening every single day for it protects against all evils and reciting ayatul kursi in the morning and evening prevents the Shaitaan from coming anywhere near you in shaa Allah and enters you into Paradise if recited after every salah. The only thing that is in the way of you entering Paradise is death. These would summarize the sources found below:

Abu Dawood: Narrated Abdullah ibn Khubayb (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings be upon him) said: Recite Qul Huwallahu Ahad (Surah Ikhlas) and Al-Mu'awwadhatain (Surah Al-Falaq And Surah An-Nas) in the evening and in the morning, three times, and that will suffice you against everything (from all evils)

Sahih Bukhari: Narrated by 'Aisha (may Allaah be pleased with her) Whenever the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings be upon him) went to bed every night, he used to cup his hands together and blow over it after reciting Surat Al-Ikhlas, Surat Al-Falaq and Surat An-Nas, and then rub his hands over whatever parts of his body he was able to rub, starting with his head, face and front of his body. He used to do that three times.

Ayatul kursi is mentioned in a narration by Abu Umaamah, the holy Prophet (saw) was quoted to have said: “Whoever recites Aayat al-Kursiy immediately after each prescribed prayer, there will be nothing standing between him and his entering Paradise except death.”

The holy Prophet (saw) was quoted to have said that “Whoever recites Ha Mim Al-Mu’min – up to – To Him is the return (40:1-3) and Ayat Al-Kursi when he reaches (gets up in) the morning, he will be protected by them until the evening. And whoever recites them when he reaches the evening, he will be protected by them until the morning.” (Jami at-Tirmidhi)

And Allah knows best. May Allah bestow upon us of His mercy and protect us from evil and may He ease our affairs. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Aleikum
When you are hit by such thoughts say:
Aamantu Billaahi Wa Rasuulihi

A few helpful solutions:

1. Always maintain wudhu
2. Keep on remembering Allah (Dhikr)
3. Recite Quran or listen if possible
4. Keep good company of those who remind you of Allah.
5. Avoid places that trigger these thoughts outside the home.
6. Avoid all sins
7. Forgive and pardon others
8. Lessen your speech to what is necessary
9. Give something in charity if you can
10. Help the poor, elderly and sick
11. Seek forgiveness constantly from Allah (Recite Astaqfirulah at least 100 times a day)
12. Recite Durood (send Salaams) upon the Prophet Muhammad (SalaLaahu Aleyhi Wa Salam)
13. Keep good company. Avoid those engaged in amusements and play all the time.
14. If parents are alive seek their forgiveness and treat them well. Ask them to pray for you.